# How does vector's begin() and end() work, and how should I write it for my custom vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I am currently studying Bjarne's PPP, and I don't really understand how begin() and end() works, and how I am supposed to implement it.

Here is my code for the `vector`.

```cpp
template<typename T> class vector {
    int sz;
    T *elem;
    int space;
    std::allocator<T> alloc;
public:
    vector():sz{0},elem{nullptr},space{0}{}
    explicit vector(int s):sz{s},elem{new T[s]}, space{s}{
        for(int i = 0; i<sz; i++) elem[i]=0;
    }
    T &at(int n);
    const T &at(int n) const;
    void reserve(int newalloc);
    void resize(int newsize, T def=T());
    int capacity() const { return space;}
    void push_back(int d);
    vector &operator=(const vector &a);

    T *begin();
    const T *begin() const;
    T *end();
    const T *end() const;

    unsigned long size();
};
```

Comment: Fortunately, pointers are valid iterator, you might return `elem`/`elem + sz` for `begin()`/`end()`.

Comment: `elem[i]=0` won't works for any `T`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`begin()` and `end()` should return an iterator. Basically, iterator is a class that implements variables such as `iterator_category` and `value_type`, which let other functions to know how to use it.

It should also implement functions required by the `iterator_category` that you choose to use.

For your a vector, you need a [random access iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). You need two classes: constant access iterator (returned by `const` function) and non-constant access iterator. Usually you would derive the non-constant class from the constant class.

The positions pointed by the iterators: `begin` points to the beginning of the data, and `end` is `begin() + size()`.

```
template<typename T>
class vector_iterator {
public:
    typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef const value_type& reference;
    typedef const value_type* pointer;

    // Functions come here
    
    // You must implement some operators
    reference operator*() const { /* must implement */ }
    vector_iterator operator+(const difference_type) const { /* must implement */ }

    // Some operators can use the operations that are already implemented
    vector_iterator operator-(const difference_type n) const { return *this + (-n); }
    reference operator[](const difference_type n) const { return *(*this + n); }
};
```

Comment: `iterator is a class that implements variables such as iterator_category and value_type` 1. Iterators aren't necessarily classes 2. iterator_category and value_type are generally not variables but rather member type aliases. 3. Iterators don't need to have those member type aliases although they often do.